# Regex Dollar Amount with Spaces

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for an expression that will return `$55.66` from this `$         55          66`

Note: the amount of spaces between the $ and number could vary. 
It will also need to work if the value is less than $10 i.e, something like `$         6         05`

Comment: Does it matter if greater than 100? 1000? How would $10,000.00 be formatted if relevant? What have you tried already?

Comment: You and I both brother. Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

For the simple case you've described, you could just split and concatenate the string.

```
s = '$ 55 66'
s = s.split()
print s[0] + s[1] + '.' + s[2]
>>> $55.66
```

To support commas

```
s = '$ 424 552 66'
s = s.split()
print s[0] + ','.join(s[1:-1]) + '.' + s[-1]
>>> $424,552.66
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular expression to find the dollar amount.

```
 re.findall(r'(\$?\d+[,\.]\d+);
```